# Why did Molly say this lines in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, mollys-game

In a room scene from *Molly's Game* (2017), the lawyer's daughter enters with papers in hand. The lawyer,
alone with his client Molly, sees the essays and is impressed. He then
sends his daughter out.

> Lawyer: Why don't you grab a snack and start your homework in one of
> the  conference rooms. Okay. See ya.
>
> Molly: **There's no law that says you can't just hit him in the head**.
>
> Lawyer: There is a law that says that.

Why did Molly say this lines in this scene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a joke. Stella has been given extra work by her (nice) father (Charlie), and Molly used to have the same (but much much more and worse) with her (authoritarian) father (Larry).

At the time, she really would have been able to "fight" (stop) her father from giving her a hard time sometimes, so she just tells the joke about "*how to get rid of your father to get rid of the extra work*".